# leaflet marker mouseover событие генерируется два раза

Tags: leafletjs

При наведении на маркер mouseover отрабатывается два раза, может кто-то сталкивался

Comment: Надо код смотреть. mouseover на маркере или на группе маркеров? А не может быть два маркера друг на друге?

Comment: Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/Novakand/bqukr3hc/31/ Если группа маркеров и и расположены рядом то бывает залипает  icons , marker остается как выбранный

Answer (score 0):

Событие `mouseover` срабатывает не один раз после наведения, а при движении курсора над элементом, количество срабатываний зависит, от нескольких факторов.

То есть это может быть по одному событию, на каждый пиксель элемента пройденный под курсором, если курсор двигать медленно.

Вероятно вам нужно событие `mouseenter`.

Comment: Решил проблему указал для css img pointer-events: none; Может кому пригодиться